# Android Compose - Can't use Modifier.align()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use Compose version 1.0.0-beta06, I can't call `Modifier.align()` method

build.gradle

```
    // Compose
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-beta06'

    // Compose Accompanist
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.9.1'

    // Compose other libs
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:1.0.0-beta06")
```

Library contain this method
[image: image-1]

But, I can't call it
[image: image-2]

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Is your `Row` inside of a `Box`? As per the library code you showed, `align` only applies within a `BoxScope` (i.e., for the direct children of a `Box`). What are you trying to do with `align`?

Comment: Oh thank @ianhanniballake, my Row isn't inside Box. I understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `align()` method is part of the `BoxScope` DSL. In order to use the method
, you should be inside a `Box`, not inside a `Row` as in your example.